# How do I apply reply back buttons to whispers?

Tags: smooch

I am trying to use simple reply back buttons in my initial whisper. I would like the user to be able to choose between (Yes,No)

Comment: You need some more details. "Smooch" appears to be an API for several platforms, but you haven't said what you're using.

Comment: using smooch.io I'm sorry I thought I was posting this into the smooch, channel.

Comment: It appears to be the right tag, but there's no indication if you're looking for a solution in JavaScript, Objective C, or Brainfuck. You need more tags. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Laurel, I am just trying to use the whispers in the backend of Smooch.io Setting up a whisper allows me to add an action button. I would like to add a reply back button in my initial whisper. But this does not seem possible.

Comment: Listen: I'm not an expert in Smooch, and I can't answer your questions. The only way that this question will get an answer is if you add more details, especially tags, which will help people find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to add `reply` type buttons to a whisper. The only supported button types at the moment are `link` and `action`.

If you need automated messages with `reply` buttons, you could achieve that using the [POST message API](http://docs.smooch.io/rest/#post-message).